# "npm run start" not creating a local server for my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React JS I created my react app using "npx create-react-app"
When the app is created successfully I tried to run the app with the following command "npm run start", but the ap doesn't create a local server it will just pop with the pic below

[image]

[image]

And when I select chrome it opens nothing below is the screenshot of the page in chrome

[image]

I'm currently using node version 14.16.1
Thanks for helping out

Comment: After creating the new project did you `cd` into the new directory and install the project dependencies, (`npm install`) before running `npm start`?

Comment: All the dependencies are present i also tried to run "npm install" and its still showing the "open with" dialog

Comment: What happens if you expand that `NPM SCRIPTS" section in the explorer and click the play button on the "start" script and run it from Vscode?

Comment: The answer below worked thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `npm start` instead of `npm run start`

Comment: Try running it in command prompt instead of Viscose powershell